# Not able to query the user data from firestore db in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a angular project and connected it to a firestore database. I also created a user using that.

My problem is that I'm not able to retrieve the data from firestore and store it locally.

appuser.ts file

```
    export interface User {
    uid: string;
    email?: string;
    photoURL?: string;
    displayName?: string;
    drawings?: [{
        id?: string;
        canvasfile?: string;
        shared?: boolean | false;
    }];
```

component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.service";
import { User } from "../../models/appuser";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: "app-drawspace",
  templateUrl: "./drawspace.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./drawspace.component.css"]
})
export class DrawspaceComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private afs:AngularFirestore) {}
  public availableUsers: any;
  users: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchAvailableUsers()
  }

  fetchAvailableUsers() {
    this.availableUsers = this.afs
      .collection<User>('users')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(docArray => {
          return docArray.map(doc => {
            let userss: User = {
              uid: doc.payload.doc.id,
              displayName: doc.payload.doc.data().displayName,
              email: doc.payload.doc.data().email,
              photoURL: doc.payload.doc.data().photoURL
            };
            return userss;
          });
        })
      );
      console.log("here see == ", this.availableUsers); // I get observable
      console.log("here see == ", this.availableUsers); // I get object

  }

}
```

when I run this,
I get a observable type, when I try to console.log, it gives me [object OBJECT], and I can't even use *ngFor on it.

I'm new to angular and firebase firestore, kindly help me to get the user data I stored successfully.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to console log `this.availableUsers.length` to check if what you got there is an array or not. And if you want to display the content of an object in console, then log only that object, don't create interpolations because in your case, the `log` method calls `.toString()` on `this.availableUsers`, that's why you get [object Object]. Try with `console.log(this.availableUsers)` and come back with what you got ;)

Comment: I tried  `console.log(this.availableUsers.length)` and got a `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript [object Object] is a string representation of an object. If you want to view the contents try `console.log(JSON.stringify(thatObj))`

```js
 fetchAvailableUsers() {
    this.availableUsers = this.afs
      .collection<User>('users')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(docArray => {
          const data = []
          docArray.forEach(doc => {
            let userss: User = {
              uid: doc.payload.doc.id,
              displayName: doc.payload.doc.data().displayName,
              email: doc.payload.doc.data().email,
              photoURL: doc.payload.doc.data().photoURL
            };
            data.push(userss)
          });
          console.log(data)  //console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
                      ^^^^
          return data
        })
      );
```

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thanks for your answer, but it is giving me a compilation error `error TS7034: Variable 'data' implicitly has type 'any[]' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.` at `const data = []` line.

Comment: @Avatar please try `const data: any[] = []`

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yeah that solved the compilation error, but console is giving nothing. I think its not going over through that loop because I tested it by keeping a general console.log, it showed me nothing.

Comment: @Avatar are you able to `console.log(docArray)` before the for loop? Also try `docArray.docs.forEach(..)` i.e loop on`.docs` property.

Comment: @Dharmaraj that gave a error `error TS2339: Property 'docs' does not exist on type 'DocumentChangeAction<User>[]'.`

Comment: @Avatar can you confirm the forEach is running by adding a log statement in it ? Without .docs

Comment: @Dharmaraj I did what you asked and I found that `.map(docArray => {` is itself not looping.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be the fact that JavaScript runs your instructions synchronously, which means that it sends the request to firebase, and goes to displaying the list of users without waiting to get the result from the request

Try displaying the list of users via tap, and let me know if you got something.

```
fetchAvailableUsers() {
  this.availableUsers = this.afs
    .collection<User>('users')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(
        // your mapping goes here...
      ),
      tap(users => console.log(users))
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but its not outputting anything.

Comment: Let's take it step by step. Let's ensure that some data is actually being fetched from firebase. Commend all the code from `fetchAvailableUsers()` and write the following snippet inside: `this.afs.collection('users').snapshotChanges().subscribe(result => console.log(result));` If something is displayed, it means that we can go further to the mapping part :)

Comment: Hey, I got something.. `{…}]
0: {type: "added", payload: t}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[{…}]
0: {type: "modified", payload: {…}}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[{…}]
0: {type: "modified", payload: {…}}
length: 1 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)


`